# List of default implementations for @property getters and setters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, properties

@synthesize'd Objective-C properties are great. Sometimes though, it's needed to customize the behavior of a getter or setter. I'm searching for a list of default implementations for all the 12 (3*2*2) different scenarios:

- assign/retain/copy
- nonatomic or not
- getter and setter

**EDIT** I'm searching for standard Objective-C implementations, not the low-level Clang implementation of synthesized properties. Unfortunately, [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) only mentions a few of above's scenarios but not the more "exotic" atomic ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's available in the source code of Clang. See [this](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/CodeGen/CGObjC.cpp), in particular `CodeGenFunction::GenerateObjCGetter` and `CodeGenFunction::GenerateObjCSetter`. Note that it's not that Objective-C code is first generated and then compiled; it's directly done. The rough idea is that for nonatomic assigned mode, or in the GC-only mode, the direct reading/writing code is generated. Everything else is handled by secret runtime functions `objc_setProperty` and `objc_getProperty`.

Their definitions, in turn, can be found [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m).

In any case, it's not something you want to copy first and then modify. Apple might change the detailed form of the implementation any time, without breaking the semantics.

I would recommend you to just write the standard setter/getter we used to write before properties are introduced. 
Note that you can have `@synthesize foo` and your custom setter `setFoo:` in your `.m` file. Then only the getter is generated. Similarly with the other case.

Or, one way is to synthesize a property with a slightly different name from the one you want to customize. Suppose you have

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*foo;
```

in your `.h` file. I would put in the `.m` file

```
@interface Foo (private)
     @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString*_foo;
@end

@implementation Foo
@synthesize _foo;
```

and put the customization in `foo:` and `setFoo:`:

```
-(NSString*)foo{
      ... do something ...
      return self._foo;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea with the slightly differently named property. In most cases however, it's just easier and more self-documenting to write the code by hand. What I'm actually searching for, are implementations for those getters and setters that **behave** the same like the low level Clang implementations but are written in standard Objective-C.

Comment: Have you read the source code of `obj_{set,get}Property` I linked above: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-437.1/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m ? That's the code handling the atomicity, etc. It's fairly readable and it's in standard Objective-C code. Well the lock uses `spin_lock_t` but you can substitute it with any other lock.

Comment: It's definitely a good read to understand their locking approach (+1 for that). I was hoping though that someone already did the work to put the code together as plain Obj-C Code one could use to build custom accessors.

Comment: Accepting this answer as the best one. I still had hoped for some readymade code I could use to built custom accessors upon.